# Access Sharepoint From Project Professional 2007 Using VBA

Tags: sharepoint, vba, ms-project

I have many Microsoft Project Servers and I have written a Project Guide that I would like each one to use. Because I only want users of a particular server only having access to their server and not others, I need to store the Project Guide on the SharePoint of each server. In Project Professional 2003, is there a way of knowing the URL in VBA (an object maybe) to its own server that it is installed on.

This is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
Sub Currently()
  OptionsInterfaceEx ProjectGuideContent:="https://example.com/SERVER_NAME/Shared%20Documents/Project%20Guide/xmlschemas.xml"
End Sub

Sub What_I_Would_Like()
  OptionsInterfaceEx ProjectGuideContent:=Application.ServerAddress & "Shared%20Documents/Project%20Guide/xmlschemas.xml"
End Sub
```

I am doing this so I do not have to edit the URL for each server we have.

Any questions please ask,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

An approach we took to solving a similar problem was to implement a simple "who am I?" web service which you host on a given server. From reading around on StackOverflow it looks as if it is possible to make web service calls from VBA. The web service simply returns the IP address or host name it sees the request coming from, and you use this to build your URL.